# Authentication Request mystery source

Tags: password, authentication

I recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS.

An authorization request dialog repeatedly appears saying, "*Please enter the password for account "bozoonthebus"*.

I used to have a Yahoo email address with that account name, but I suspect I must have used that name for something else on my previous Ubuntu version. I have checked Ubuntu accounts and apps like Thunderbird, but find no account by that name.

***Is there a way to determine what is making this request, so I can either delete it or somehow remedy it??***

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute a file search and found accounts.conf with the offending login name. I renamed the file to accounts.conf.bak and rebooted.

```
~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf
```